# Left Outer Join using DefaultIfEmpty throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 lists (reports, userPrinters, allPrinters) which I join together using LINQ. `reports` contains a list of reports, `userPrinters` contains the user's preferred printer name and paper source for each report (might be empty or not one-to-one with the reports list) and `allPrinters` is a list of printers on the system (might not have the same printers as the user's printers).

So my query is:

```
var list = (from r in reports
    join u in userPrinters on r.Id equals u.ReportId into up
    from userPrinter in up.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join p in allPrinters on userPrinter.PrinterName equals p.Name into ps
    from printer in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new PrinterSelection() {
        Report = r,
        Printer = printer,                 
        Source = (from s in printer.Sources
           where s.Type == userPrinter.PaperSource
           select s).FirstOrDefault()
       }).ToList();
```

So with the above query, I get all the reports, left outer join the user's printers and then left outer join all printers.

However, when I include the 2nd left outer join, I get a `NullReferenceException`.

Should `DefaultIfEmpty` return a default singleton? What am I missing?

Comment: The zero-argument version of `DefaultIfEmpty()` returns the default for the type, eg 0 for an int, etc. The default for a reference type is `null`. If you want it to create a new object then that would be the argument to the one-argument version of `DefaultIfEmpty`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @lakobski's comment. I missed the constructor with the default value. So this is the updated LINQ that works:

```
var list = (from r in reports
    join u in userPrinters on r.Id equals u.ReportId into up
    from userPrinter in up.DefaultIfEmpty(new UserPrinter())
    join p in allPrinters on userPrinter.PrinterName equals p.Name into ps
    from printer in ps.DefaultIfEmpty(new Printer())
    select new PrinterSelection() {
        Report = r,
        Printer = printer,                 
        Source = (from s in printer.Sources
           where s.Type == userPrinter.PaperSource
           select s).FirstOrDefault()
       }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to do null check for userprinter variable like below,

```
join p in allPrinters on (userPrinter== null ? "no-value" : userPrinter.PrinterName) equals 
p.Name
```